# Error when using DejaVu Serif and Sylfaen fonts for Armenian language

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec

I am trying to use Armenian language in Latex.
I have read from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization that I can use following commands to have Armenian font:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
```

or

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Sylfaen}
```

My document class is `\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}`.

But I am getting following errors when compiling either with XeLatex or LuaTex:

[image]

The same for Xelatex

[image]

```
Log :
    ! Undefined control sequence.
    <argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                               Erroneous variable \c__fontspec_shape_n_n_tl used!
    l.3806 \emfontdeclare{ \emshape, \eminnershape }

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           Erroneous variable \c__fontspec_shape_n_it_tl used!
l.3806 \emfontdeclare{ \emshape, \eminnershape }

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           Erroneous variable \c__fontspec_shape_it_n_tl used!
l.3806 \emfontdeclare{ \emshape, \eminnershape }

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I have simple code I have the same error either writing in Armenian or English letters:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Sylfaen}
\begin{document}
Some Text
Ինչ-որ բան
\end{document}
```

Thanks,in advance.

Comment: Can you add the error when compiling with xelatex too? Also a MWE would be good...

Comment: My version of Miktex is 2.9 as well. ("..\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.cfg")

Comment: @TatevikPetrosyan You need an update of the MiKTeX *packages*; the version number 2.9 refers to the infrastructure, but the various parts of LaTeX get updated much more frequently than MiKTeX.

Comment: I have updated all recommended packages in MikTex but still get the same error. :(

Comment: @egreg I have deleted fonspec package and run my file again. The new fontspec package was added and it is workable.
Thanks you all!

Comment: You need to update miktex with both update managers (the user and the admin version). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108490/2388.